# Porter/Duff XOR operation on basic shapes in OpenGL possible?

Tags: c++, c, opengl, alphablending, porter-duff

I have a triangle shape :

```
void myTriangle()
{

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glColor4f(0,0,1,1);
        glVertex2f(0, 0.5);// 
        glVertex2f(-0.5,-0.5);//
        glVertex2f(0.5,-0.5);//
    glEnd();
}
```

And I have a square shape :

```
void mySquare(double R,double G,double B,float A)
{
    glBegin(GL_QUADS); 
      glColor4f(R,G,B,A);
      glVertex2f(-0.5f, -0.5f); 
      glVertex2f( 0.5f, -0.5f);
      glVertex2f( 0.5f,  0.5f);
      glVertex2f(-0.5f,  0.5f);
    glEnd();
}
```

I want to intersect the two shapes to show an xor effect like :

[image: Porter/Duff XOR]

Is this possible in OpenGL and how would I go about doing this if it is feasible ?
I'm also using GLUT and GLUI libraries just as a side-note in-case there are any tricks I can pull of with them .

Comment: Draw the first shape in a FBO, the second shape in another FBO, then draw a quad blending the two FBO contents using a custom fragment shader?